# пишет `drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride`

Tags: linux, c, gtk

Ой, не пойму что не так, уже поисправлял кучу ошибок, но это всё равно не работает. выводит вот такие ошибки.

```
(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkPaned': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkNotebook': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.931: drawing failure for widget 'GtkApplicationWindow': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkDrawingArea': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkViewport': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkScrolledWindow': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkPaned': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkFrame': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkNotebook': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkBox': invalid value for stride

(gtiles:35551): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:44:25.948: drawing failure for widget 'GtkApplicationWindow': invalid value for stride
```

Что может быть не пойму. вот код. через меню создайте проект, а потом добавьте картинку. резать по 64x64 пикселя например. после нажатия на добавить и закрыть и рисуется окно нормально и эти ошибки. вот код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <png.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

GtkApplication *app;

struct widgets {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *notebook;
    GtkWidget *header;
    GtkWidget *window_ap;
    GtkWidget *entry_ap;
    GtkWidget *button_ap;
    GtkWidget *entry_width_ap;
    GtkWidget *entry_height_ap;
    GtkWidget *button_add_ap;

    GtkWidget *STUBS;
} w;

struct image {
    int width;
    int height;
    unsigned char *bytes;
    int pos;
};

struct list_files {
    int id;
    char *filename;
    char *name;
    GtkWidget *drawing;
    GtkWidget *frame;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *button_close;
    GtkWidget *frame_pics;
    GtkWidget *scroll_frame_pics;
    GtkWidget *draw_pics;
    GtkWidget *paned;
    GtkWidget *framen;
    GtkWidget *label_name;
    GtkWidget *box_label;
    GtkWidget *box_frame;
    GtkWidget *label_layer;
    GtkWidget *spin_layer;
    GtkWidget *box_layer;
    double pos_x;
    double pos_y;
    int size_width;
    int size_height;
    char *pic_path;
    int size_pics;
    struct image **im;
    cairo_surface_t **sur;
    struct list_files *next;
} *lf;

struct list_files *lm;

static void static_init_list_files ( ) {
    lf = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct list_files ) );
}

static char *get_dialog_file_name ( const char *title, const char *apply, GtkFileChooserAction action ) {
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    GtkFileChooser *chooser;
    int res;

    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ( title,
            ( GtkWindow * ) w.window,
            action,
            "Отмена",
            GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
            apply,
            GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
            NULL
            );

    chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER ( dialog );

    gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation ( chooser, TRUE );

    res = gtk_dialog_run ( GTK_DIALOG ( dialog ) );

    if ( res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT ) {
        char *filename;
        filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename ( chooser );
        gtk_widget_destroy ( dialog );
        return filename;
    }

    gtk_widget_destroy ( dialog );
    return NULL;
}

static gboolean draw_pics_draw_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data ) {
    cairo_set_source_rgb ( cr, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    cairo_paint ( cr );

    int x = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < lm->size_pics; i++ ) {
        cairo_set_source_surface ( cr, lm->sur[i], 0, 0 );
        x += lm->size_width;
    }

    cairo_fill ( cr );

    return FALSE;
}
static gboolean draw_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data ) {

    struct list_files *l = ( struct list_files * ) data;

    cairo_set_source_rgb ( cr, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    cairo_paint ( cr );

    int width, height;
    width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width ( widget );
    height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height ( widget );

    cairo_set_source_rgb ( cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    int x, y;

    for ( x = l->pos_x, y = l->pos_y; y < height; y += l->size_height ) {
        cairo_move_to ( cr, x, y );
        cairo_line_to ( cr, width, y );
    }
    for ( x = l->pos_x, y = l->pos_y; x < width; x += l->size_width ) {
        cairo_move_to ( cr, x, y );
        cairo_line_to ( cr, x, height );
    }
    cairo_stroke ( cr );

    return FALSE;
}

static int btn_m;
static int px;
static int py;

static gboolean draw_button_motion_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    GdkEventMotion *evm = ( GdkEventMotion * ) event;
    struct list_files *l = ( struct list_files * ) data;

    if ( btn_m ) {
        int x = evm->x;
        int y = evm->y;

        l->pos_x -= x - px + l->size_width;
        px = x;
        l->pos_y -= y - py + l->size_height;
        py = y;

        gtk_widget_queue_draw ( l->drawing );
    }

    return FALSE;
}
static gboolean draw_button_press_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    GdkEventButton *evb = ( GdkEventButton * ) event;

    if ( evb->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS && evb->button == 2 ) {
        btn_m = 1;
        px = evb->x;
        py = evb->y;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
static gboolean draw_button_release_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    GdkEventButton *evb = ( GdkEventButton * ) event;

    if ( evb->type == GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE ) {
        btn_m = 0;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

static void notebook_switch_page_cb ( GtkNotebook *notebook, GtkWidget *page, int page_num, gpointer data ) {
    struct list_files *l = lf;
    while ( l->next ) {
        if ( l->id == page_num ) {
            lm = l;
            return;
        }
        l = l->next;
    }
}

static void activate_new_project ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    struct list_files *l = lf;
    while ( l->next ) l = l->next;

    l->filename = get_dialog_file_name ( "Новый проект", "Создать", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE );

    if ( !l->filename ) return;

    l->name = strrchr ( l->filename, '/' );
    l->name++;

    l->frame = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, NULL );
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    GtkWidget *drawing = gtk_drawing_area_new ( );
    l->drawing = drawing;
    l->size_width = l->size_height = 64;
    g_signal_connect ( drawing, "draw", G_CALLBACK ( draw_cb ), l );
    g_signal_connect ( drawing, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK ( draw_button_press_event_cb ), l );
    g_signal_connect ( drawing, "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK ( draw_button_release_event_cb ), l );
    g_signal_connect ( drawing, "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK ( draw_button_motion_event_cb ), l );
    gtk_widget_add_events ( drawing, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK | GDK_BUTTON2_MOTION_MASK );
    GtkWidget *paned = gtk_paned_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL );
    l->paned = paned;

    GtkWidget *frame = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, NULL );
    l->framen = frame;
    gtk_widget_set_size_request ( drawing, 1080, -1 );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request ( frame, 196, -1 );

    gtk_paned_pack1 ( ( GtkPaned * ) paned, drawing, FALSE, FALSE );
    gtk_paned_pack2 ( ( GtkPaned * ) paned, frame, FALSE, FALSE );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, paned, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) l->frame, box );

    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ( l->name );
    l->label_name = label;
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ( "exit" , GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU );
    l->button_close = button;
    GtkWidget *box_label = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    l->box_label = box_label;
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_label, label, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_label, button, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    GtkWidget *box_frame = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    l->box_frame = box_frame;
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame, box_frame );

    GtkWidget *label_layer = gtk_label_new ( "Слой" );
    l->label_layer = label_layer;
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_layer, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_layer, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( label_layer, 16 );

    GtkWidget *spin_layer = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range ( 0, 100, 1 );
    l->spin_layer = spin_layer;
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( spin_layer, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( spin_layer, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( spin_layer, 16 );

    GtkWidget *box_layer = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    l->box_layer = box_layer;
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_layer, label_layer, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_layer, spin_layer, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    l->frame_pics = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, NULL );
    l->draw_pics = gtk_drawing_area_new ( );
    g_signal_connect ( l->draw_pics, "draw", G_CALLBACK ( draw_pics_draw_cb ), l );
    l->scroll_frame_pics = gtk_scrolled_window_new ( NULL, NULL );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) l->scroll_frame_pics, l->draw_pics );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) l->frame_pics, l->scroll_frame_pics );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( l->frame_pics, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( l->frame_pics, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( l->frame_pics, 16 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( l->frame_pics, 16 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_frame, box_layer, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_frame, l->frame_pics, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    gtk_notebook_append_page ( ( GtkNotebook * ) w.notebook, l->frame, box_label );
    l->id = gtk_notebook_page_num ( ( GtkNotebook * ) w.notebook, l->frame );

    g_signal_connect ( w.notebook, "switch-page", G_CALLBACK ( notebook_switch_page_cb ), NULL );

    lm = l;

    gtk_widget_show_all ( l->frame );
    gtk_widget_show_all ( box_label );
    gtk_widget_show_all ( w.notebook );

    l->next = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct list_files ) );

}
static void activate_save_project ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
}
static void activate_save_as_project ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
}
static void activate_quit ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    g_application_release ( ( GApplication * ) app );
}

static void activate_add_picture ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    gtk_widget_show_all ( w.window_ap );
}

static void button_add_ap_cb ( GtkButton *button, gpointer data ) {
    int width, height;
    png_byte color_type;
    png_byte bit_depth;
    png_bytep *row = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen ( lm->pic_path, "r" );
    png_structp png = png_create_read_struct ( PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    if ( !png ) {
        fclose ( fp );
        return;
    }

    png_infop info = png_create_info_struct ( png );
    if ( !info ) {
        fclose ( fp );
        png_destroy_read_struct ( &png, NULL, NULL );
        return;
    }

    if ( setjmp ( png_jmpbuf ( png ) ) ) {
        fclose ( fp );
        png_destroy_read_struct ( &png, &info, NULL );
        return;
    }

    png_init_io ( png, fp );

    png_read_info ( png, info );

    width = png_get_image_width ( png, info );
    height = png_get_image_height ( png, info );
    color_type = png_get_color_type ( png, info );
    bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth ( png, info );

    if ( color_type != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA ) {
        fclose ( fp );
        png_destroy_read_struct ( &png, &info, NULL );
        return;
    }


    int ww = atoi ( gtk_entry_get_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_width_ap ) );
    int hw = atoi ( gtk_entry_get_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_height_ap ) );

    int fill_width = width / ww;
    int fill_height = height / hw;

    int co = 0;

    row = calloc ( height, sizeof ( png_bytep ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
        int count = png_get_rowbytes ( png, info ) / 4 / ww;
        row[i] = calloc ( png_get_rowbytes ( png, info ), 1 );
        co += count;
    }
    co /= height;

    png_read_image ( png, row );
    fclose ( fp );
    png_destroy_read_struct ( &png, &info, NULL );
    if ( fill_width == 0 ) fill_width = 1;
    if ( fill_height == 0 ) fill_height = 1;


    lm->size_pics = co;
    lm->im = calloc ( fill_width * fill_height, sizeof ( struct image * ) );
    for ( int y = 0; y < fill_height; y++ ) {
        lm->im[y] = calloc ( width, sizeof ( struct image ) );
        for ( int x = 0; x < fill_width; x++ ) {
            lm->im[y][x].bytes = calloc ( ww * 4 * hw, 1 );
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for ( int y = 0, x = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++, i += 4 ) {
            int pos = lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].pos;
            lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].pos += 4;
            lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].bytes[pos + 0] = row[y][i + 3];
            lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].bytes[pos + 1] = row[y][i + 1];
            lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].bytes[pos + 2] = row[y][i + 2];
            lm->im[y / hw][x / ww].bytes[pos + 3] = row[y][i + 0];
        }
        i = 0;
    }

    lm->sur = calloc ( fill_width * fill_height, sizeof ( char * ) );
    lm->size_pics = fill_width * fill_height;

    for ( int y = 0; y < fill_height; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < fill_width; x++ ) {
            lm->sur[i] = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data ( lm->im[y][x].bytes, CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, ww, hw, 0 );
        }
    }

    gtk_widget_queue_draw ( lm->draw_pics );
}

static void button_ap_cb ( GtkButton *button, gpointer data ) {
    int index = gtk_notebook_get_current_page ( ( GtkNotebook * ) w.notebook );
    if ( index == -1 ) return;
    if ( lm->pic_path ) g_free ( lm->pic_path );

    lm->pic_path = get_dialog_file_name ( "Открыть картинку", "Открыть", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN );

    if ( !lm->pic_path ) return;

    gtk_entry_set_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_ap, lm->pic_path );
}

static gboolean window_ap_delete_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data ) {
    gtk_widget_hide ( w.window_ap );
    return TRUE;
}

static void static_init_add_picture ( ) {
    w.window_ap = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    g_signal_connect ( w.window_ap, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK ( window_ap_delete_event_cb ), NULL );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( ( GtkWindow * ) w.window_ap, 400, 200 );
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) w.window_ap, box );

    GtkWidget *box_path = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    GtkWidget *label_path = gtk_label_new ( "Путь к файлу png" );
    w.entry_ap = gtk_entry_new ( );
    w.button_ap = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "Выбрать" );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_path, label_path, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_path, w.button_ap, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_path, w.entry_ap, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, box_path, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( box_path, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( box_path, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( box_path, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_path, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_path, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( label_path, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( label_path, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( w.entry_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( w.entry_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( w.entry_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( w.button_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( w.button_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( w.button_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( w.button_ap, 8 );

    w.entry_width_ap = gtk_entry_new ( );
    w.entry_height_ap = gtk_entry_new ( );
    gtk_entry_set_width_chars ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_width_ap, 4 );
    gtk_entry_set_width_chars ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_height_ap, 4 );
    GtkWidget *box_wh = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    GtkWidget *label_width = gtk_label_new ( "width" );
    GtkWidget *label_height = gtk_label_new ( "height" );
    gtk_entry_set_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_width_ap, "32" );
    gtk_entry_set_text ( ( GtkEntry * ) w.entry_height_ap, "32" );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_wh, label_width, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_wh, w.entry_width_ap, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_wh, label_height, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_wh, w.entry_height_ap, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( box_wh, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( box_wh, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( box_wh, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( box_wh, 32 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_width, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( label_width, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_width, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_height, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_height, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( label_height, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( label_height, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( w.entry_width_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( w.entry_width_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( w.entry_width_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( w.entry_height_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( w.entry_height_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( w.entry_height_ap, 8 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, box_wh, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    w.button_add_ap = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "Добавить" );

    g_signal_connect ( w.button_add_ap, "clicked", G_CALLBACK ( button_add_ap_cb ), NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( w.button_ap, "clicked", G_CALLBACK ( button_ap_cb ), NULL );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box, w.button_add_ap, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( w.button_add_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( w.button_add_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( w.button_add_ap, 8 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( w.button_add_ap, 8 );
    
}

static void static_create_app_menu ( ) { 
    const GActionEntry entries[] = {
        { "new_project", activate_new_project },
        { "save_project", activate_save_project },
        { "save_as_project", activate_save_as_project },
        { "add_picture", activate_add_picture },
        { "quit", activate_quit }
    };

    g_action_map_add_action_entries ( G_ACTION_MAP ( app ), entries, G_N_ELEMENTS ( entries ), NULL );

    GMenu *menu_root = g_menu_new ( );
    GMenu *menu_project = g_menu_new ( );
    g_menu_append ( menu_project, "Новый проект", "app.new_project" );
    g_menu_append ( menu_project, "Сохранить проект", "app.save_project" );
    g_menu_append ( menu_project, "Сохранить проект как ...", "app.save_as_project" );
    g_menu_append_submenu ( menu_root, "Проект", ( GMenuModel * ) menu_project );
    g_menu_append ( menu_root, "Добавить Sprite Sheet", "app.add_picture" );
    g_menu_append ( menu_root, "Выход", "app.quit" );

    gtk_application_set_app_menu ( ( GtkApplication * ) app, ( GMenuModel * ) menu_root );
}

static void app_activate_cb ( GtkApplication *app, gpointer data ) {
    static_init_list_files ( );

    w.window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    gtk_window_maximize ( ( GtkWindow * ) w.window );
    w.box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) w.window, w.box );

    static_init_add_picture ( );

    w.notebook = gtk_notebook_new ( );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) w.box, w.notebook, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    w.header = gtk_header_bar_new ( );
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) w.header, TRUE );
    gtk_header_bar_set_decoration_layout ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) w.header, ":menu,minimize,maximize,close" );
    gtk_window_set_titlebar ( ( GtkWindow * ) w.window, w.header );

    static_create_app_menu ( );

    gtk_widget_show_all ( w.window );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    app = gtk_application_new ( "org.xverizex.gtiles", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_application_register ( ( GApplication * ) app, NULL, NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( app_activate_cb ), NULL );
    return g_application_run ( ( GApplication * ) app, argc, argv );
}
```